# How to create Github actions to deploy a Blazor Server project on Azure targeting appsettings.Staging.json?

Tags: c#, azure, github-actions, blazor-server-side, azure-appservice

I have a C# Blazor server project deployed on Azure App Service using Github actions.
Deployment is OK, but the WebSite uses **appsettings.json** instead of **appsettings.Staging.json**.

I think the environment should be defined, but I cannot find how to do this.

I've tried to provide

/p:EnvironmentName parameter to "dotnet publish", without success.

```
env:
  API_RESOURCE_NAME: myappapica
  MYAPP_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging

jobs:
  build:
    environment: 
      name: staging
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: "6.0.x"

      - name: Install wasm-tools
        run: dotnet workload install wasm-tools

      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.STAGING_AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Set backend env variables
        uses: azure/powershell@v1
        with:
          azPSVersion: "latest"
          inlineScript: |
            az extension add --source https://workerappscliextension.blob.core.windows.net/azure-cli-extension/containerapp-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl --yes
            az provider register --namespace Microsoft.App
            $apiUrl = "https://$(az resource show -g ${{ secrets.STAGING_AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }} -n ${{ env.API_RESOURCE_NAME }} --resource-type Microsoft.App/containerApps -o tsv --query properties.configuration.ingress.fqdn)"
            echo "MYAPP_API_URL=$apiUrl" | Out-File -FilePath $Env:GITHUB_ENV -Encoding utf-8 -Append

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build src/Web/MyApp.Web --configuration Release

      - name: Publish
        run: dotnet publish --configuration Release src/Web/MyApp.Web /p:EnvironmentName=${{ env.MYAPP_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT }} --output web

      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: drop
          path: web

    outputs:
      MyAppApiUrl: ${{ env.MYAPP_API_URL }}
```

My appsettings:

```
{
  ...
  "WebConfiguration": {
    "EnvironmentCode": "PRODUCTION",
  }
}
```

My appsettings.Staging.json :

```
{
  ...
  "WebConfiguration": {
    "EnvironmentCode": "STAGING",
  }
}
```

My web site always shows EnvironmentCode="PRODUCTION" instead of "EnvironmentCode": "STAGING".

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by going back to fundamentals :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0

For Azure App Service, it requires to add an application settings "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT". As I didn't want to do it manually on Azure portal, I updated my deploy job to add a new App Service app settings variable.

```
  app-settings-json: |
            [
                {
                    "name": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
                    "value": "${{ env.MYAPP_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT }}"
                }
            ]
```

Here is a large part of the yml file.

```
  env:
  API_RESOURCE_NAME: myappapica
  # Warning : This is case sensitive !
  MYAPP_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging

jobs:
  build:
  ......[SOME CODE]......
  
  deploy:
    needs: build
    environment: 
      name: staging
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' && (github.event_name == 'push' || github.event.pull_request.merged == true || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch') }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-lastaging
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.STAGING_AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Deploy ARM
        uses: azure/powershell@v1
        with:
          azPSVersion: "3.1.0"
          inlineScript: |
            az deployment group create -n ghaction -g ${{ secrets.STAGING_AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }} --template-file deploy/Web/staging.web.deployment.json --parameters webAppName=${{secrets.STAGING_WEBAPP_NAME}} servicePlanName=${{secrets.STAGING_SERVICE_PLAN_NAME}} servicePlanSku=${{secrets.STAGING_SERVICE_PLAN_SKU}}

      - name: Download web artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: drop
          path: web
      
      - name: Collect App Service app settings variables
        uses: azure/powershell@v1
        with:
          azPSVersion: "3.1.0"
          inlineScript: |
            az extension add --name application-insights
            $applicationInsightConnectionString ="$(az monitor app-insights component show -g ${{ secrets.STAGING_AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }} --app ${{ secrets.STAGING_APPLICATION_INSIGHT_NAME }} -o tsv --query connectionString)"
            echo "APPLICATION_INSIGHT_CONNECTION_STRING=$applicationInsightConnectionString" | Out-File -FilePath $Env:GITHUB_ENV -Encoding utf-8 -Append
            
      
      - name: Update App Service app settings variables
        uses: Azure/appservice-settings@v1
        with:
          app-name: ${{ secrets.STAGING_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          app-settings-json: |
            [
                {
                    "name": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
                    "value": "${{ env.MYAPP_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT }}"
                }
            ]

      - name: Azure WebApp
        uses: Azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ secrets.STAGING_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          package: web
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Blazor Server App and deployed to Azure App Service using GitHub Actions.

If we deploy the App using `Deployment Center` => `GitHub Actions` by default, the workflow file will be created with `Production` settings in the `.yaml` file.

[image]

[image]

- Instead of using the `Deployment Center` => `GitHub` from Azure Portal, we need to create the workflow manually in `GitHub Repository`.

In Git Hub, add the new Environment.

[image]

- Create a new Workflow with [staging](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/about-deployments/deploying-with-github-actions) environment.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [Using AppSettings in Blazor WebAssembly](https://jkdev.me/blazor-appsettings/?github) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be what I want. But I can't try it, because I don't have access to Environnents in Github (i'm using a Free but Private repository, and Environments are not available in this condition).